# PayPal Payments REST API on ColdFusion

Tags: rest, paypal, coldfusion

Has anyone implemented PayPal REST API on ColdFusion?

I would like to see some approaches, since there is no SDK or anything that could make the life of a CF developer easier with PayPal REST API.

Essentially, what I need is some starting point to help me implement Authorize, Capture, Refund and Void through ColdFusion.

Comment: Start reading the documentation. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/. Then do that with ColdFusion. Have you tried getting an access code with `CFHTTP`? If not, then what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the response Adrian. I tried reading it and it is a bit confusing. I was unable to understand the difference between v1 and v2, I was unable to find a proper example for authorization and capturing (at the same time, not two different requests) etc.

To answer your question though, I was able to get an access code with cfhttp, but I still have some questions. How long is this valid for and what actions can I use this for?

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm assuming the paypal REST API is like most other REST APIs... you generate a token that you pass in with every request, which validates and authorizes your requests. The trick is figuring out how to configure each of your HTTP requests so that it includes your token and your request data. Typically, your token is passed with your request headers, and your request data is passed as JSON in the body of the HTTP call. After you get those two things figured out, it shouldn't be too hard to build a CFC that will communicate with PayPal.

Comment: If you have a basic understanding of how to use any REST API, then you should be able to use an app like Postman to test calls to the PayPal REST API. PayPal's docs give a pretty good explanation of how to get credentials initially, and then how to use those creds to get an access token, and then how to pass that access token in when making API requests. Once you can follow those steps in Postman, then translating it into cfhttp calls should be straightforward. I'd suggest not writing any API code until you can follow the Postman examples. Translating to cfhttp after that is the easy bit.